# Why NetGroup.MulticastStream.UnpublishNotify fires just after NetGroup.MulticastStream.PublishNotify

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, adobe, netstream, adobe-cirrus

I am working on Cirrus I want to make audio chat. I publish stream on one side but its **NetGroup.MulticastStream.PublishNotify** event doesn't fires at first time....When I publish it twice or thrice it fires. I play the stream on the other side using published stream name but just after **play** event firing **NetGroup.MulticastStream.UnpublishNotify** fires and I can't listen the voice.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I guess `NetGroup.Multicast Stream.PublishNotify` fires only when NetStream contains information (for example if you connected microphone but not speaking, netStream will be open but don't contain information in stream). 
For example try send some data like this `_myStream.send("onFunction","sata");` after `_myStream.publish("name");` and `NetGroup.Multicast Stream.PublishNotify` must fires in a first time.